# Bluetooth 4.0 Dongle detectable by iPhone 4S/5

Tags: bluetooth, iphone

I bought a CSR Bluetooth 4.0 dongle, when plugged into my computer, initially my iPhone 5 could not detect it, but if I set the dongle to broadcast as Headset mode in the Bluetooth settings, the iPhone detects it instantly.

**I am wondering how to configure the Dongle so that if I plug it into a USB car jack (for example), the iPhone can detect it right away?**

Are there any tools or software that I need?